# E/AndroidRuntime( 6851): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 123 Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Here is my console, I working with the google maps flutter. getting this continuously on console I/Counters( 6851): exceeded sample count in FrameTime and then get this error

```
I/Counters( 6851): exceeded sample count in FrameTime
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6851): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 123
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6851): Process: estibafy.com.estibafy_user, PID: 6851
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6851): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6851):    at java.nio.ByteBufferAsIntBuffer.put(ByteBufferAsIntBuffer.java:122)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6851):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.buffer.n.i(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214218120@21.42.18 (190800-0):2)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6851):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.buffer.n.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214218120@21.42.18 (190800-0):3)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6851):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.drawable.d.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214218120@21.42.18 (190800-0):3)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6851):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.drawable.ao.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214218120@21.42.18 (190800-0):9)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6851):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bz.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214218120@21.42.18 (190800-0):29)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6851):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bs.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214218120@21.42.18 (190800-0):151)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6851):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.av.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214218120@21.42.18 (190800-0):48)
    D/EGL_emulation( 6851): app_time_stats: avg=2145.86ms min=60.17ms max=14501.58ms count=7
    I/Process ( 6851): Sending signal. PID: 6851 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Did you try to delete app cache and restart it in your emulator or simulator?

Comment: Yes many times, even I have deleted app completely from my emulator, wipe data of emulator then run again, but issue still same.